# Grabbing passwords on a Win 2003 domain

Tags: active-directory, passwords, windows-server-2008, windows-server-2003

I've recently been given the task at a school which runs a local domain to grab a copy of all the passwords when we reset them this week (students and staff).

The reasoning for this is because we wish to have them in sync with our local proxy server passwords and 3rd party user based applications.

I've had a look into *passwdhk* but haven't been able to get it running cleanly on our machines. We have 1x Windows Server 2008 RC2 machine and 1x Windows Server 2003 machine - we're running a 2003 domain because of this.

I'm wondering if anyone can help. I'm looking at something similar to passwdhk - some sort of custom password filter. However I'm not a higher level programmer and wouldn't be able to write this in C or C++. Can anyone point me in the direction of one I could easily modify or point out another solution?

The other option I was thinking of was to force all users to log into an intranet page with an ASP.NET backend that presented them with a form and sent it via a WSO or something - that way I'd have a plain text copy.

Your thoughts and input would be highly, highly appreciated!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You would need a custom password filter, or a password sync product. Forefront Identity Manager is one which can do this but you're not going to get this (or likely any solution) setup in a week.

A web based self service interface is pretty common, but, you won't be able to use the native Windows functionality to communicate password expiry.